# How to properly fix - Cannot use empty array elements in arrays

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below but it showing an error "Cannot use empty array elements in arrays".

It seems that the issue is in this line `}),  collect(json_decode($post['comments'], true))->map(function ($comment) {`

Code:

```
'data' => [
    'comments' =>
    collect(json_decode($configs['comments'], true))->map(function ($comment) {
        return [
            'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
            'message' => $comment['attributes']['message'],
        ];
    }),  collect(json_decode($posts['comments'], true))->map(function ($comment) {
        return [
            'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
            'message' => $comment['attributes']['message'],
        ];
    }),
]
```

Comment: can you show me the JSON string that you are decoding?

Comment: It has this format "^ "[{"key": "o0Gdz1EsxOpOLN", "layout": "comment", "attributes": {"title": "a", "comment": "b"}}]"
".

Comment: @Bernard if that is the case, both maps attempt to get the `message` property from the `attributes` object. In the data you provided, that object uses the property key `comment`, not `message`.

Comment: Would be good if OP could add the json string to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplify your code it seems like this;

```php
'data' => [
    'comments' =>
       collect(),  
       collect()
]
```

It is not a valid syntax. You can try like this;

```php
$comments = collect(json_decode($configs['comments'], true))->map(function ($comment) {
    return [
        'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
        'message' => $comment['attributes']['message'],
    ];
});
$postComments =  collect(json_decode($posts['comments'], true))->map(function ($comment) {
    return [
        'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
        'message' => $comment['attributes']['message'],
    ];
});

'data' => [
    'comments' => $comments->merge($postComments)->toArray()
];
```